# Search entire file for a pattern; every time it's found, delete up until a certain character appears

Tags: search, gvim

I'm trying to search for the string `/c` in the entire file, and when it's found I'd like to delete everything - including the `/c` itself - up until the next occurrence of `/` (but not the `/` itself). For the purposes I'm using this for, you can assume that:

1. not every line will have a `/c` in it,
2. but when there is one in a line, it will always be the only one in that line, and
3. there will always be a `/` following it at some point in that same line.

I've learned of macros recently, and I found that if I create a macro with `qa/\/c<CR>dt/q` and then run it a large number of times with `:g//normal 500@a`, that it will make all the desired deletions (until it gets to the end of the file when it gives the error `E486: Pattern not found: \/c`). But I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do it - with some kind of `:%s` search command - that requires only one line. I'm quite certain there is, I just don't know how to do it. Alternatively, if a command or function could be created in the `_vimrc` file that would accomplish this task, that would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following command should do what you need:

```
:g:/c:s:/c[^/]*/:/:
```

Breaking it up:

- `:g`: for every line that satisfies the condition

  - that it match `/c` (note, I'm using `:` as the regex delimiter for convenience, or I'd have to escape each `/` that I use)
- run `s:/c[^/]*/:/:`, which:

  - looks for `/c`, followed by any number of non-`/` characters and then a `/`, and
  - replaces it with a `/`. In effect, it leaves one `/` in place of the matched text, which includes both the boundary `/`.

Of course, you could have used your macro and run:

```
:g:/c:normal @a
```

The trick is to only run on those lines which match your condition.

Comment: Okay, I was a bit confused at first with all the `:` 's but your note reminded me that it could be used in place of `/` in order to avoid having to make all the other `/` 's into `\/` 's. And I didn't know how to run the macro _only_ on the lines that matched the condition. Thank you, @muru for the explanation. (Also, in my original question which I saw you edited, I thought that it was only "code" that should be put in the grey text box, so that's why I used quotes to refer to the `/c` pattern and the `/` character, but I'll remember to put these things in the grey text in the future.)

Comment: @ablewasiereisawelba it's important to note that even quotes could be meaningful - what happens if you needed to match `"foo bar"`, or use a register via `"a`? Use code formatting for things that should displayed exactly as meant to be used.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what is the difficulty:

```
:%s:/c.*\ze/::
```

or

```
:%s:/c.*/:/:
```

This searches in the whole file for `/c` followed at some point by `/` on the same line and:

- either replaces the pattern, excluding the final `/`, with nothing (1st form)
- or, the whole pattern is replaced by a single `/` (2nd form)

In order to avoid escaping `/` I simply used a different substitute separator (`:`). `.*` means "any number of unspecified characters, but only in the same line".

If more than one `/c.*/` construct per line is possible, simply add `g` at the end to replace them all.

**Note**: the above match is greedy (matches until the last `/` on the line, "swallowing" all others into the pattern). For a non-greedy match, use `[^/]*` instead of `.*`. There is also `.*\{-}`, but it may not work with the 1st solution (before `\ze/`).

Comment: OP says "up until the next occurrence of `/`", so use non-greedy matching or `[^/]*` instead of `.*`.

Comment: Indeed, duly noted :)

Comment: I found that @VanLaser 's initial solution had deleted the `/` as well, but his edited answer now works like I want it to. Thanks for the answer and explanation.

Comment: Yes, I often find myself going for the solution when I got the main part, but not all the details.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the part about "greedy" versus "non-greedy", because in my file, the next `/` is always the last `/` in each line. When I realized what that was referring to, I put an extra `/` at the end of the first line just to test it out, and saw that it was deleting everything up to the end of the line. Also, replacing `.*` with `.*\{-}` doesn't seem to work for either solution.